# How to toggle sidebar with button on actionbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, sidebar

I have a button on the actionbar of my android app, which toggles a sidebar. The problem is , I don't know when the user clI ka the button to open the sidebar and when to close it. This is because pressing the back button or clicking on the area outside the sidebar also closes the sidebar. So  how can I make the button on the actionbar to effectively toggle the sidebar open and close?

Answer (score 0):

Your sidebar should have a public method that returns whether it is open or not. Or, just call toggle() on it and it will open it if closed (or vice versa)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the sidebar code, it is an external library (scringo). I'll need some other way to do this..